# Invalidate AWS Cognoto token at logout

Tags: python, swift, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm building Swift application with Python backend, and I'd like to use AWS Cognoto for authentication and registration flow.

Currently, I'm using following code to log in

```swift
let user = pool?.getUser(email)
user?.getSession(email, password: password, validationData: nil)
    .continueWith { task in
        // handle error/success

        return nil
    }
```

Pool is initialized above, using `self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.default()` call.

On app startup, I'm checking, if user is authenticated, and getting it's access_token:

```js
if AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn {
    if let user = pool?.currentUser() {
        user.getSession()
            .continueWith { task in
                token = task.result?.accessToken?.tokenString

                return nil
            }
    }
}
```

And I'm passing this token to backend. On backend, I'm getting user's data via Python Warrant library:

```python
from warrant import Cognito

u = Cognito("id", "key", user_pool_region="us-east-1")
u.access_token = "token"

res = u.get_user(attr_map={"sub": "user_id", "email": "email"})
```

If token is valid, I'm getting user's data, otherwise, exception is risen. But after the logout on client, this token is still alive. I'm using following logout code:

```swift
AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().logout { (result: Any?, error: Error?) in
    // handle results
}
```

I understand, that this token will expire after some timeout, and won't be refreshed, as on next login user will get another accces/refresh tokens pair, but I'd like to invalidate token immediately on signout, is it possible? Or I don't understand Cognito and use it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scouring through github and AWS forums, I found a (semi) answer to this question by chris radek, a contributor to the aws-sdk for js.

Here is that discussion: 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1241

If you don't want to read all of it, basically, chris says that its standard for the tokens to be valid for an hour, but

> by modifying a certain parameter you can cut that down to a minimum of
>   15 minutes. You cannot, however, invalidate a token immediately on
>   signout.

Here are the javascript docs that describe how to cut down the duration of time:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html#params-property

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRoleWithWebIdentity-property

The AWS Documentation over the topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232652

Here is the matching function that can be called in python:
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity

This is where the token duration can be changed!

Comment: Thank you, I've though that answer will be something like that, but I hoped there will be some solution